# JQuery disabled textbox not turning lightgray

Tags: jquery, css

I have some JQuery that disables my textbox. By default it is not turning the color light gray. So I added more JQuery to turn it lightgray when disabled but I would like it to go back to it's default CSS (that I created in my style sheet). 
Is there anyway to basically but a lightgray ask on the textbox when disabled and remove it when it is off?

**Current JQuery**

```
    if ($("#checkBoxName").is(":checked")) {
        $("#textBoxName")
            .attr("disabled", "disabled")
            .val("")
            .css("background-color", "lightgray")
    }
    else {
         $("#textBoxName")
            .removeAttr("disabled")
            .css("background-color", "red");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Here is a link for anyone else that may need it in the future http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Comment: Also, you should use `.prop('disabled', true)` instead of `.attr()`. `.prop()` has been implemented to target boolean attributes.

Comment: ahh thank you while doing research people kept saying to use .prop() but didn't give reasons why.

Comment: You're welcome. Forgot to add: examples of boolean attributes are `disabled`, `readonly`, `selected`, `checked` and etc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create new rules in your css for the lightgrey style by doing

```
#textBoxName:disabled { 
    background: lightgrey;
}
```

For more info :
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3adisabled)

Answer (score 0):

A way of achieving is is combine the CSS with two classes, and instead of adding the CSS you add the classes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').click( function(){
        if ( $('#textBoxName').hasClass('red') ) {
            $('#textBoxName').removeClass('red').addClass('grey');
        } else {
            $('#textBoxName').removeClass('grey').addClass('red');
        }
    })
});
```

That way, you may control the CSS it's been applied, and you can "remove the CSS applied" XD. Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VdJ97/

Answer (score -1):

```
//if (document.getElementById('uno').checked) {} else {}

$(function(){
$('#checkBoxName').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#textBoxName")
            .attr("disabled", "true")
            .val("")
            .css("background-color", "silver")
    }
    else {
         $("#textBoxName")
            .removeAttr("disabled")
            .css("background-color", "red");
    }
});    
});
```